# Will moving some content from application to library reduce memory footprint c++

Tags: c++, linux

We have an app running on low memory Linux device and we are trying to reduce the memory foot print of the app, flash and ram. Will moving some of the classes (500) which does a specific business logic to a separate library help.

Comment: Why do you think it would help?